# Excel Date and Time Generator

Tags: excel, date, time

I am solving the following problem in Excel. I need to generate for each day a minute-to-minute rows from 09 to 17. It should look like this:

```
Time
01.01.2013 09:00
01.01.2013 09:01
01.01.2013 09:02
01.01.2013 09:03
01.01.2013 09:04
01.01.2013 09:05
01.01.2013 09:06
01.01.2013 09:07
01.01.2013 09:08
01.01.2013 09:09
01.01.2013 09:10
```

and so on for another 10 years. Also the weekends should be excluded (if this is not possible, it would be nice  to at least to mark in next column which rows are weekends and which not).

Is there any solution for this, to generate this kind of time dimension?

Comment: Are you just asking how to format a DateTime to look like that?

Comment: which version of excel you want to do so?

Comment: Nono, I need to generate these times. Its so time consuming to do it manually. For every day in a year there s need to be 480 rows with time minute by minute. Excel is 2010.

Comment: Selecting the first two rows then click/dragging down the column doesn't take that long, I think.

Comment: Well, this is not a solution as this does not work. It only works for one day (one date), so you need to create day by day manually anyway afterwards. Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell A1 enter: `01.01.2013  09:00:00` or whatever your first date and time is.
In cell A2 enter:

`=IF(TIME(HOUR(A1);MINUTE(A1);SECOND(A1))=TIMEVALUE("17:00");WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);DAY(A1));1)+TIMEVALUE("09:00");A1+1/24/60)` drag cell A2 down to fill as necessary.

what the formula does is checking the previous date time to see if time is "17:00":

***IF*** `TIME(HOUR(A1);MINUTE(A1);SECOND(A1)) = TIMEVALUE("17:00")`

If it's true, then it skips to next working day (skipping weekends) at time "09:00":

***THEN*** `WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);DAY(A1));1)+TIMEVALUE("09:00")`

Else it adds 1 minute (1/24/60th part of a day):

***ELSE*** `A1+1/24/60`

PS1: if you do not want to skip weekends modify in formula the ***THEN*** part as follows:

```
DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);DAY(A1)) + 1 + TIMEVALUE("09:00")
```

PS2: you would get to end of Excel rows (1048576) after about 8 years and 5 months...

Comment: Great, thank you a lot! It works perfectly, you are the best. Btw additional question - is there any possibility to also skip some specified dates (holidays)? E.g. to create some list with the holiday array list and exclude these dates from it?

Comment: yes, you can... put your dates in a row or column.... then pass the range as third argument for WORKDAY function, suppose you have B1:B15 with holidays... the THEN part would look like this: WORKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);DAY(A1));1; ***$B$1:$B$15*** )+TIMEVALUE("09:00")